# Changing field length through PHP Script

Tags: sugarcrm

I Want to change field length through a PHP script and Sugar beans in both database and Sugar CRM studio

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is quite broad and not suitable to this site. See [ask]

Comment: How about going to the studio and do the required changes there?

Answer (score 1):

You're question is very vage and doesn't show us what you've already tried, but I'll give it a go regardless:

**Custom fields**

Studio saves custom fields in *DynamicFields* beans, which are saved in database in the `fields_meta_data` table. The field's id is module name + field name, e.g. `Accountstests_c` for field `test_c`.

One way to change it is by updating the `len` column in the table and then run a Quick Repair & Rebuild (see notes below).

Alternatively you could adjust the field using the *DynamicFields* beans or using the ModuleBuilder's PHP controller similar to how Studio does it (I'll try to add an examples later).

**Stock fields**

You can adjust a field's length using [Vardefs-Extensions](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Architecture/Extensions/Vardefs/).

E.g. if you want to change length (vardef attribute `len`) of the varchar-field `name` in module `Accounts` to 100:

`./custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_name.php`:

```
<?php
$dictionary['Account']['fields']['name']['len'] = 100;
```

**Notes**

- Run a [Quick Repair & Rebuild](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Troubleshooting/Performing_a_Quick_Repair_and_Rebuild/index.html) and your change will be applied in Sugar and Studio. Then scroll down and run the suggested DB changes.
  If you want to do this without user interaction find or write a sugarcrm repair script.
- When creating new Vardef extensions make sure to use the *BeanName* for the dictionary array index, so `Account` for `Accounts` or `aCase` for Cases. If unsure what to use, just see how existing vardefs files of the module in question do it.
- For available vardefs attribute names and more insight into vardefs see [here](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Data_Framework/Vardefs/) or look at the `vardefs.php` files in the `modules/` subfolders.

Comment: I want to change the length for custom field in accounts module